# FreeBSD pf.conf. Error: "no IP address found for wlan0:network"

Tags: networking, freebsd, pf

Every time I try to make some sensible `pf` rules - I fail. Need someone to help me with the puzzling syntax and mechanics of `pf`.

Here is my pf.conf:

```
 1 # The name of our network interface as seen in `ifconfig`                                                             
 2 ext_if="re0"                                                                                                          
 3 usb_if="ue0"                                                                                                          
 4 wlan_if="wlan0"                                                                                                       
 5 wlan_network = $wlan_if:network                                                                                       
 6                                                                                                                       
 7 all_ifs = "{" $ext_if $usb_if $wlan_if "}"                                                                            
 8
 9 # Macros to define the set of TCP and UDP ports to open.
10 # Add additional ports or ranges separated by commas.
11 # UDP 60000-60010 is mosh control http://mosh.mit.edu/
12 tcp_services = "{ ssh, http, https, smtp, domain, www, pop3, auth, pop3s }"
13 udp_services = "{ 60000:60010, domain, ntp }"
14
15 # If you block all ICMP requests you will break things like path MTU
16 # discovery. These macros define allowed ICMP types. The additional
17 # ICMPv6 types are for neighbor discovery (RFC 4861)
18 icmp_types = "{echoreq, unreach}"
19 icmp6_types="{echoreq, unreach, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137}"
20
21 # send RST
22 set block-policy return
23
24 # log interface on cable->ISP
25 set loginterface $ext_if
26                                                                                                                       
27 # Exempt the loopback interface to prevent services utilizing the                                                     
28 # local loop from being blocked accidentally.                                                                         
29 set skip on lo0                                                                                                       
30                                                                                                                       
31 # normalize all incoming traffic                                                                                      
32 scrub in on $ext_if all fragment reassemble                                                                           
33                                                                                                                       
34 # block and log everything  by default                                                                                
35 block return log on $ext_if all                                                                                       
36                                                                                                                       
37 # block anything coming from source we have no back routes  for                                                       
38 block in from no-route to any                                                                                         
39
40 # block packets whose ingress interface does not match the  one in
41 # the route back to their source address
42 block in from urpf-failed to any
43
44 # block and log outgoing packets that do not have our address as source,
45 # they are  either spoofed or something is misconfigured (NAT disabled,
46 # for instance), we want to be nice and do  not send out garbage.
47 block out log quick on $ext_if from ! 31.41.112.52 to any
48
49 # block and log incoming packets from reserved address space and invalid
50 # addresses, they are either spoofed or misconfigured, we cannot reply to 51 # them anyway (hence, no return-rst).                                                                                 
52 block in log quick on $ext_if from  { 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, \                                                    
53   192.168.0.0/16, 255.255.255.255/32 }  to any                                                                        
54                                                                                                                       
55 # Enable antispoofing on all interfaces                                                                               
56 antispoof quick for $all_ifs                                                                                          
57                                                                                                                       
58 # drop broadcast requests quietly.                                                                                    
59 block in quick on $all_ifs from any to 255.255.255.255                                                                
60                                                                                                                       
61 # ICMP                                                                                                                
62                                                                                                                       
63 # pass out/in certain ICMP  queries and keep state (ping)                                                             
64 # state matching is done on host addresses  and ICMP id (not type/code),                                              
65 # so replies (like  0/0 for 8/0) will match queries                                                                   
66 # ICMP error messages (which always refer to a TCP/UDP packet) are                                                    
67 # handled by the TCP/UDP states                                                                                       
68  pass on $ext_if inet proto icmp all icmp-type 8 code 0                                                               
69                                                                                                                       
70 # UDP                                                                                                                 
71
72 # pass out  all UDP connections and keep state
73 pass out on $ext_if proto udp all
74
75 # pass in certain UDP connections and keep  state (DNS)
76 pass in on  $ext_if proto udp from any to any port domain                                                             
77                                                                                                                       
78 # TCP
79
80 # pass out  all TCP connections and modulate state                                                                    
81 pass out on $ext_if proto tcp all modulate  state                                                                     
82
83 # pass in certain TCP connections and keep  state                                                                     
84 pass in on  $ext_if proto tcp from any to any port $tcp_services                                                      
85                                                                                                                       
86 # IPv6
87 # pass in/out all IPv6 traffic: note that we have to enable this in two
88 # different ways, on both our physical interface and our tunnel
89 pass quick on $ext_if proto ipv6
90
91 # NAT on wi-fi
92 nat on $ext_if from $wlan_network to any -> ($ext_if)
93 pass from ($wlan_network) to any keep state                                                                           
94
```

The error is :

> /etc/pf.conf:92: could not parse host specification
> pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded

I have a wifi dongle connected, every now and then, to my laptop. The device is configured to be in access point state. So I can transfer my internet connection from laptop to other devices. What I want to do, is to pass packets to and from local wifi network to an external interface. I use NAT for that. When the dongle is connected, everything goes fine. But at most time it is not.

My thoughts are that, that since wifi dongle are not connected at a regular basis, there is no `$wifi_network`. And since that, there is an error.

How can I solve the situation? In other words, how to make a `pf` rule execute on a condition that I have a wifi network interfce?

Answer (score 0):

I had to reformat my `pf.conf`.

Simply changing `wlan_network` to `wlan_network = "{ 192.168.0.1/24 }"` solved the error.
The `NAT` rule goes as `nat on $ext_if from $wlan_network to any -> ($ext_if)`.
The `pf` now reads network as string. And since `pf` executes rule only
if it passes through the given interface from given addresses, the rule is not being run
in the absense of `wlan0` interface.

Had tested the above with WI-FI on/off.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your line 92 should have parenthesis as well, like this:

```
nat on $ext_if from ($wlan_network) …
```

— see line 93: `pass from ($wlan_network) to any keep state`